# Folder and subfolder copy at MSDOS

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory, xcopy, robocopy, directory-structure

I have a folder with 9500 documents inside(let's call if folder1). I want to make a copy of this folder with the structure it have but i want in the new folder(let's call it folder2) all the documents to be blank. Folder1 contains several type of documents. Untill now i have as code :

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\Users\DM\Desktop\folder1\*.*"
set "dest=C:\Users\DM\Desktop\folder2"

xcopy "%source%" "%dest%" /t/e
for /f "tokens=2 delims=>" %%a in ('xcopy "%source%" "%dest%" /s/h/e/k/f/c/l') do (
for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ("%%a") do type nul >"%%b"
)
pause
```

The bat goes ok, but after a while there are 3 different errors on the cmd and it stacks there (my windows are greek so i'm trying to translate the errors). One is that "memory is not enough" , the next one is "The system cannot locate the disk(or drive) path specified"   (it's one of the two drive/disk i think.) and the last one is "File name syntax, directory or volume label is incorect". It stops at a specific htm file that has "<>" characters on the title.

Can you please tell me what should i add? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Certainly seems odd. Theoreticall, it should be impossible to have `>` or `<` in a filename. The `/k` is redundant as the `/L` switch is used, and `/e` implies `/s` so `/s` is also redundant - but those are cosmetic. I'd also prefer `copy nul "%%b" >nul` but again, that would be personal preference. Could you `ECHO(+%%a+` before the `for...%%b` and report results with a part-dir list of the offending series of filenames? Quite where the insufficient-memory and cannot-locate messages are popping up from - heaven knows. Are you sure `dest` is not a subdirectory of `source`?

Comment: This user has a `Greek` OS and may also have `Unicode` filenames.  Maybe someone can offer him the code page to use for his region, to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the code below will help. But it echo the new line to all files. And I couldn't use source as parameter in !fileRelPath:C:\te mp\=!

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set source=C:\te mp\
set dest=C:\te mp2\

if not exist "%dest%" mkdir "%dest%"

xcopy "%source%*" "%dest%" /t /e

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /B /S /A-D "%source%"') do (
    set fileRelPath=%%a
    set fileRelPath=!fileRelPath:C:\te mp\=!

    echo.>"%dest%!fileRelPath!"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Magoo says, this is strange.

Anyway, while finding where this fails, you can do the same with

```
robocopy "%source%" "%dest%" * /e /create
```